# Eclipse Commandline Arguments with String[] args

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I need to enter a String input, format it, and display the output in a certain format. I'm supposed to use the Run > Run Configuration > Arguments > Program Argument and I entered in any string (ie. "test") in the Program arguments section. When I try to run the java application, I keep getting an error message in the Console window. How do I use the Commandline arguments? What should I enter in the program arguments? Any help with this, would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Below is the error message that I get in the Console window:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at a00752124.data.InventoryReader.read(InventoryReader.java:26)
    at a00752124.Lab2.<init>(Lab2.java:38)
    at a00752124.Lab2.main(Lab2.java:28)
```

Below is my sourcecode for the main class:

```
public class Lab2 {

    /**
     * Main method of Lab2 class
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Lab2(args[0]);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for Lab2 class
     * 
     * @param itemCount
     */
    public Lab2(String itemCount) {

        Item[] items = InventoryReader.read(itemCount);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));

        InventoryReport.display(items);
        }

    }
```

Here's the source code for my InventoryReader's read method:

```
public static Item[] read(String input) {
        String[] rows = input.split(":");
        Item[] items = new Item[rows.length];

        int i = 0;
        for (String row : rows) {

            String[] element = row.split("\\|");
            items[i] = new Item(element[0], element[1], Integer.valueOf(element[2]), Float.valueOf(element[3]));
            i++;


        }

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: The exception occurred in `InventoryReader.read()` method. Can you show us that method? The exactl location is `InventoryReader.java` line 26.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your input. I added the source code for my InventoryReader's read method above.

Comment: It seems u need to give input with `:` as row delimiter and `|` as column delimiter with 4 elements in row

Comment: Thanks I tried that but it's still giving errors. I'm still getting an exception thrown from the line "items[i] = new Item(element[0], element[1], Integer.valueOf(element[2]), Float.valueOf(element[3]));"

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
String row = "";
```

then:

```
String[] element = row.split("\\|");
```

What is the size of `element` after you split an **empty** string?

Right after you assume that `element` has at least **4** items.

```
items[i] = new Item(element[0], element[1], Double.valueOf(element[2]), Double.valueOf(element[3]));
```

Clear enough?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I fixed the InventoryReader's read method but I'm still getting errors. It's throwing an exception on the line "items[i] = new Item(element[0], element[1], Integer.valueOf(element[2]), Float.valueOf(element[3]));" Any ideas?

Comment: I believe it's still the same error.  To test your assumption about the size of your `element` array place `System.out.println(element.length);` before the problematic statement or (even better) use a debugger and put a breakpoint on this line.